# How to know whether a SDNode has physical instruction associated with it?

Tags: llvm

As both target independent IR and target specific instruction can be represented as `SDNode`, is there a function to tell whether the `SDNode` has physical instructions associated with it which means it has been lowered or passes instruction selection?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dyn_cast<MachineSDNode>(N)` or `isa<MachineSDNode>(N)`